# Count line values in Pig

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

In a data file like this:

```
1000054,4946631
1000065,4748968
1000067,4944640_5071294_5312208
1000086,4178246_4217220_4686189_4839046
```

Is it possible to count the values on the right side of the comma and generate soemthing like this:

```
1000054, 1
1000065, 1
1000067, 3
1000086, 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible, In `Option1` you need to split the second part using `STRSPLIT` function with `'_'` as delimiter and convert into bag then use `COUNT` function to get the final value.

`Option2` is very simple,   just `TOKENIZE` the second part with `'_'` as delimiter and get the count.

**input:**

```
1000054,4946631
1000065,4748968
1000067,4944640_5071294_5312208
1000086,4178246_4217220_4686189_4839046
```

**PigScript1:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS(f1:int,f2:chararray);;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1, FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(f2,'_'));
C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0,COUNT(TOBAG($1..));
DUMP C;
```

**PigScript2:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS(f1:int,f2:chararray);;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1, COUNT(TOKENIZE(f2,'_'));
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(1000054,1)
(1000065,1)
(1000067,3)
(1000086,4)
```

Comment: Updated one more solution.